# How to call a javascript command in a popup window?

Tags: javascript

I opened a pop window as:
`var pop=window.open("https://qqqqqqqq.com/awssdds");`

Now I want to click something like:
`$('[value="click here"]').click();`
which is inside new opened window.
How to do this?

EDIT:
I am looking something like this:
`var pop=window.open("https://qqqqqqqq.com/awssdds");`
`pop.$('[value="click here"]').click();`
 ie, This script is in parent window. It is to avoid scripts in child window.
But its not working.. Need some modification

Comment: From what context? Is the source page and the destination both your domain, or are you using a userscript, or what?

Comment: If you want to have control over the `popup` window elements it is better to open the window using something similar to `bootstrap-modal` and display the contents as simple `HTML` inside it else whatever function you want to perform on the newly opened window has to be a part of that page's script.

Comment: You cannot reach the content of a window from another window. As soon as you open the window, it's contents are out of reach for security reasons. Otherwise, I would be able to create a website with a button called "go to my bank" and fetch a users account balance.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a parameter to your url.

```
https://qqqqqqq.com/awssdds?alertmessage=thank%20you
```

You can then retrieve the parameter in your new window with URLSearchParams

```
var v = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var message = v.get("alertmessage");
if (message) {
  alert(message)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But still need to click the button

Answer (score 0):

First thing if you want to click something after the page will be loaded.

And add the `alert` message as a query.

```
https://qqqqqqq.com/awssdds?alert=alertmsg
```

Set the `document ready` in your popup page.And show the alert message after that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Click the function after page load
   $('[value="click here"]').click();
   // get alert message and show it
   let params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
   let alert_mag = params.get("alert");
   if (alert_mag) {
     alert(message)
   }
});
```

That's it.